# Finding location of command executed

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a Bash script tell what directory it's stored in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in)

Is there a command-line function (`bash`) to find the location of the command you've executed?

I understand I could check my `$PATH` for things I've imported manually but there must be some way to do this. A tricky `echo` command or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides `whereis`, see also `which` and `type`.

Comment: `type` has the advantage of being a shell builtin, so it can tell you whether something is actually a builtin, alias or function, rather than an external command.

Comment: I liked type the most of all these. thanks!